# On the utilisation scope of chess book analytical notations

Tags: opening

Subject: usefulness of annotating games

In his volume "My games", Gary Kasparov provides commentary, in addition to the pgn (potable game notation) of his encounter's deployment variant-speculations: alternate options.

This engenders in the prospective reader, what may be characterised as the litany of theoretical-hertiage-development-backlog in the motion toward performance, in chess.

By introducing this additional relation, the author invokes what may be viewed of as the framework of existing educational systems, in chess.

As they may have existed in the former USSR.

Sadly, though, from what can be gathered, our former world champion actually garners, not an addition to his game moves, but, possibly, what may be described as, bland gesturing, toward the past; and not, as ought be, it's incorporation into what could, should, or has the potential, to be.

The question is this: if one were to compile a catalogue of encounters over-the-board, and if such a thing still presents the potential to formulate wholesale unity: by the consideration of the aforementioned, what is it that lends utilisable credence to such a thing, by way of annotating remarks?